# js to expand DataTables row is being triggered by buttons inside the row

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) 1.10.16 in an application which uses ajax-sourced row data. That means that when a user clicks on an row of the table, an ajax request is made to gather some data, and then populate the row.

Everything is done via ajax so there is no data in the table on page load. There is simple an empty `<table>` with the ID `#substancesTable`.

The way this is set up is as follows:

1. The data to populate the table is obtained from `/get-substances.json` like this:

   ```
   var substancesTable = $('#substancesTable').DataTable({
       "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
       "searching": false,
       "ajax": {
           "url": "/get-substances.json",
           "method": "POST",
           "cache": false,
           "dataSrc": function (json) {
               return json.data;
           }
    }
    // ...
   ```
2. When the user clicks on a row of the table (`#substancesTable`) it uses an if...else statement so that any visible rows would be closed (collapsing them). However, if a row is currently collapsed clicking on it will execute `expand_substance()` - see point (3).

   ```
   $('#substancesTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
       var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var row = substancesTable.row( tr );

       if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
           row.child.hide();
           tr.removeClass('shown');
       } else {
           row.child( expand_substance(row.data()) ).show();
           tr.addClass('shown');
       }
   });
   ```
3. `expand_substance()` makes an ajax request to `/expand-substance` and passes the row ID that the user has clicked on. This ajax endpoint returns HTML with further details of the substance which are then populated into the expanded row of `#substancesTable` that the user clicks on in (2)

   ```
   function expand_substance ( rowData ) {
       var div = $('<div/>').text('Loading...');

       $.ajax({
           url: '/expand-substance/' + rowData.id,
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function ( data ) {
               div.html(data);
           }
       });

       return div;
    }
   ```

The problem I'm having is that some of the HTML returned by (3) contains anchors, e.g. `<a href="/some-action" class="foo">Some action</a>`. If these are regular anchors - which do not have any js-based event listeners, they function normally. For example clicking the above would indeed take the user to `/some-action`. But, if I want to make my `.foo` anchor have an event handler, such as:

```
$('#substancesTable').on('click', '.foo', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('testing');
});
```

The browser is trying to execute `expand_substance()`, which isn't what I want. It won't get as far as the `console.log()` and will error on the basis that no `rowData` has been passed to `expand_substance()`.

I thought I could use jquery's `.not()` functionality to exclude my `.foo` class from being targetted, e.g.

```
// Modified from step (2)
$('#substancesTable tbody').not('.foo').on('click', 'td', function ()
```

But this doesn't work.

I understand the source of the problem is likely that I am targetting clicking on any `<td>` in my table with the js in point (2). But this seems to be given in DataTables examples when expanding a row and updating it with an ajax source data. The examples don't take into account that a user might want to click on something (such as a button or anchor) inside the `<td>` after the ajax has returned the content.

Can anyone help me? Essentially **I am trying to add `click` event listeners to anchors in the HTML returned by (3) in a way they won't be targeted by the click event of (2).**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the handler for .foo

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference I'm afraid

Comment: Have you tried both `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`?